# Django query using case expression to decide where inclusion

Tags: mysql, django, sqlite, mysql-python

I have a query in django which I want to use in mysql and possibly with sqlite during the test stage
if some conditions exist then some query would be included in the where part of the query i.e.

if name is provided or year is provided the query would be

`select * from tab1, tab2, tab3 where tab1.name='%s' and tab1.year=%s and tab1.id=tab1.tb2_id and tab3.id=tab1.tb3_id`

else the query should be

`select * from tab1, tab2, tab3 where tab1.id=tab1.tb2_id and tab3.id=tab1.tb3_id`

I have made use of case expression but it was giving me error.

This is the query

```
Modelname.objects.raw("select * from tab1, tab2, tab3 where
tab1.id=tab1.tb2_id and tab3.id=tab1.tb3_id and
CASE '%s'
    WHEN None
        THEN ''
    ELSE tab1.name='%s' 
END
and 
CASE %s
    WHEN None
        THEN ''
    ELSE tab1.year=%s 
END", ["user name",2])
```

error returned

```
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
return self.sql % self.params_type(self.params)
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using raw queries? Django ORM is capable of CASE/WHEN expressions and should be used instead of those. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/conditional-expressions/

As for the actual question, since you have 4 `%s` in the query, you have to provide 4 params, even if it's the same params. But the query actually looks invalid for me, and you'd better use the ORM.

```
Modelname.objects.raw("select ...", ["user name", "user name", 2, 2])
```